# Hover link to change opacity of image

Tags: image, hyperlink, hover, opacity

I am trying to get the effect shown here https://www.kogevitamins.com/

Where you hover over the "learn more" link to get the opacity of the image to also change.

Thanks.

Edit:

Right now I have

for HTML

```
    <img src="/images/pill.png" alt="description" id ="image" />
<p> Daily Essentials </p>
<a id ="button"  href="#">Learn More</a>
```

For jquery

```
    $("#button").hover(function(){
    $("#image").animate({opacity:1},300);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("#image").animate({opacity:0.6},300);;
});
```

It doesn't seem to work so far

Edit:

I have the following code recently updated but the hover on effect doesn't work for me. Heres a link to the thing I'm trying to get to work http://maninkorean.com/

```
<div class ="product-content">
<img class="imgClass" src="/images/pill.png" alt="description"  />
<p> Daily Essentials </p>
<a id ="button"  href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>

 $("a#button, img").hover(function(){
    $("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:1},300);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:0.6},300);;
});

img.imgClass{
    opacity: 0.6
}

#button {
    padding: 10px 24px;
    background:#F15951;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color:white;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can easily do this by css, with somethings like this:

```
.img {opacity:0.4; /*some more css*/  }   /* (opacity:) is now supported by all browsers */
.img:hover {opacity:0.98;  /* Some more css be creative... */  }
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using jQuery with the following code:

```
$('#id of link you want to use to change opacity').hover(function() { $('#id of image that you want to change opacity of').css({ 'opacity' : 0.25 }); });
```

Comment: I don't think this will offer a nice "fade" effect between the two different opacity images, though... might have to integrate JQuery's `fade()` method somehow.

Comment: Yes, you could certainly modify this to use jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut. API is here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: hi i think that is something i am looking for. I was wondering if I can use class instead of id or does it have to be id?

Answer (score 1):

Combine JQuery and CSS3's opacity features to wire up an "OnHover" event to the images that changes the opacity of the said image.

http://www.css3.info/preview/opacity/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to see through those images and show background pattern, there is no need to deal with opacity.

Even though you can prepare semitransparent version of image and change `src` attribute in `onMouseOver` event.

But you can achieve the same effect by simply putting a div with 1-pixel semitransparent background above selected image.

Using CSS opacity will cut off older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some html, css, jquery that shows how to do it:

```
<div></div><a>Hover On Me</a>

div{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
    background:red; 
    opacity: 0.6
}

a{
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:100px; 
    padding:5px;
    height:20px; border-radius:5px; 
    background:yellow;
}

$("a").hover(function(){
    $("div").animate({opacity:1},300);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("div").animate({opacity:0.6},300);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rd5Yy/2/

Comment: how can i add classes or id to it to make it more specific to something?

Comment: Okay, I made another fiddle for you with your code... I show you id, class, and different ways to select with jquery selector. Let me know if you get confused. http://jsfiddle.net/94sqc/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply I made edits to the code and linked to the site for more information. the hover effect on the "learn more" doesn't work for me. Also I am using drupal 7, I think it should come with jquery.

Comment: Yes, Drupal should come with JQuery. Can you make sure your selectors are working? Make sure you are selecting with id, class, tag, or whatever... maybe copy my code and test that out?

Comment: Here's another fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/gytYS/. Your code worked fine. I only added the JQuery function of document load ($(function(){}). Maybe you didn't have that. Look at my jquery in the fiddle and try it out.

Comment: I'm new to javascript/jquery I am wondering what I need in the .js file maybe that is why its not working for me because everything works well in the jsfiddle. I only have this code in the js file.  $("a#button, img").hover(function(){
    $("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:1},300);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:0.6},300);;
});

Comment: So in JavaScript or JQuery you need to tell it do this when the DOM (HTML) is loaded, but you aren't telling it anywhere so it doesn't know when to do what. In JQuery you use $(function(){all your code goes here}); and in JavaScript it's document.load and so on. So in your JavaScript (usually put your JavaScript files in bottom of body), put this: $(function(){ now put all your javascript code here   });

Comment: Your final JQuery:
$(function(){
   $("#button").hover(function(){
      $("#image").animate({opacity:1},300);
   }).mouseout(function(){
    $("#image").animate({opacity:0.6},300);;
   });
});

Comment: Currently I have $(function(){

 $("a#button, img").hover(function(){
    $("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:1},300);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:0.6},300);;
});


});   is there something else that I am missing to make the js file work? Also I should have called/connected the js file to the theme I am using in drupal.

Comment: That code should work fine. Make sure you are including the file in your HTML page.

Comment: That is weird I put the code directly with <script></script> tags into the drupal page and even recalled the javascript file there too but nothing seems to be working right now.

Comment: Okay I just checked your page, it seems your jQuery symbol isn't $. It's jQuery. In the script (jquery code I gave you), replace all the '$' with 'jQuery'.

Comment: Your final JQuery: jQuery(function(){ jQuery("#button").hover(function(){ jQuery("#image").animate({opacity:1},300); }).mouseout(function(){ jQuery("#image").animate({opacity:0.6},300);; }); });

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the specific example you cite, they've used CSS3 transitions.  See here for a tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

In a nutshell using these you can do all kind of funky effects without any javascript.  CSS3 is supported by modern browsers (but is pretty cutting edge as web technologies go) and isn't yet a W3C standard.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you wanted to do (I tested it against your HTML):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").hover(function(){
        $("#image").animate({opacity:0.6},300);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $("#image").animate({opacity:1},300);;
    });
});
```

Comment: And you can edit this to do classes by using .classname instead of #id

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just checked out your page. Firstly, it looks like jQuery is not working through the $ on your site, so you'll need to either troubleshoot that, or use it by jQuery instead. I pasted this code in on the JavaScript console on your site and it works:

```
jQuery("a#button, img").hover(function(){
    jQuery("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:1},300);
}).mouseout(function(){
    jQuery("img.imgClass").animate({opacity:.6},300);;
});
```

edit: Looks like you got it working as I was typing up this response